# css is background-color compulsory

Tags: javascript, html, css

in the page http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_text.asp we have:

> For W3C compliant CSS: If you define
>   the color property, you must also
>   define the background-color property.

It doesn't make sense to me at all, does anyone know if this is verified?

Comment: yup @david is correct use http://htmldog.com/ for any reference

Comment: Have a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html to see for yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it's defined in the spec for color contrasts

http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-CSS-TECHS/#style-color-contrast

This is there to ensure that you define a high contrast background color if you define a foreground color. Whether you do so or not depends on the colors you use. Make your page accessible

Answer (score 3):

No, this is yet another example of [W3Schools being wrong](http://w3fools.com/), don't trust them.

If you don't set the colour and the background-color at the same time, then you risk accidentally creating a low contrast element (especially once your code interacts with user stylesheets). Thus is is **good practise** to set them together and (if the warnings settings are turned up high enough) the W3C CSS Validator will *warn* you if you set the color without setting the background-color.

It is not, however, required by the CSS specification.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply NO , w3schools might be wrong in this case , as others mentioned there are lot of other errors also

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to define `background-color`. All the not using is making "pointless" warning from CSS Validator. It's not always possible to use it, like if you have colored hiperlink on irregular `background-image`. It should be like, if you use `background-image`, you should also use `background-color`. Also, be sure to set both `color` and `background-color` on `<body>`. Otherwise, you shouldn't care much...

Reference: http://www.websitedev.de/css/validator-faq